# Building an iOS app with pairing capabilities to Bluetooth Classic devices

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, react-native

I have an idea for an iOS app I'd like to build. Coming from web, I'm currently learning React-Native to build iOS apps. I was wondering if it's possible to build an app that has pairing capabilities with a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Core Bluetooth only covers Bluetooth LE.  If you want Bluetooth classic you have to sign up for [MFi](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My question now is, can you use Core Bluetooth to connect to a Mac via Bluetooth? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm not very knowledgeable in Bluetooth technology.

Comment: You need to setup your mac to act as a Peripheral that broadcasts a service.  You can then have the iOS app 1) Scan for peripherals that support your service CBCentralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: options:) 2) Connect to said peripheral CBCentralManager.connect(_, options:) 3) begin monitoring characteristics for that service CBPeripheral.setNotifyValue(_, for:).  Now whenever your Mac app updates one of its characteristics, the iOS app will get a call back on its CBPeripheralDelegate.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll look into this more. Essentially I want to be able to build an app that allows me to pass audio from my mac to my app like a bluetooth speaker.

Comment: Oh then the answer is no.  Bluetooth LE is for lower power and short data transmission.  Its way too slow for something like audio.  You are probably better off using wifi.  You can still connect over bluetooth to setup the route between the mac and the phone and then stream the data over the internet.